# Jackson include non_null not working on object from kotlin extension function

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I have a spring boot project

I have set global `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion: non_null` in application.properties which is removing all the null values except from inside a list of objects.

Also, tried adding @JsonInclude at class level , as below

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
class ClassData { 

 String classId;

 List<Students> students = new ArrayList<>();

}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

class Students {
studentId,
isVerified,
studentType

}
```

The response from my server -  It still contains null values,  but outside the list structure, the nulls are being removed

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "studentId": null,
      "isVerified": true,
      "studentType": null
    },
      "studentId": null,
      "isVerified": true,
      "studentType": null
    },
      "studentId": null,
      "isVerified": true,
      "studentType": null
    },
      "studentId": null,
      "isVerified": true,
      "studentType": null
    },
      "studentId": null,
      "isVerified": true,
      "studentType": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my converted method in kotlin which is converting StudentDetail from another service to internal Student object

```
fun StudentDetail.toStudent(): Student {
    return Student().apply {
        transactionId = transactionId
        isVerified = isVerified
        transactionType = transactionType
    }
}
```

Spring boot version - 2.2.6.RELEASE

Rest all objects are working fine , nulls being removed except ClassData?  Will appreciate any help

Comment: how you return this resonose?  your error not reproduceable.. which spring-boot version u using?

Comment: spring boot version is 2.2.6.RELEASE. , return the response as ResponseEntity.ok(someClass.getResponse())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Objects were generated from openapi specs, where studentId and studentType were set as required.  Hence, they were coming in the response. Fixed them.